# alerting you when a hdd is missing with software windows raid

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, mirroring, disk-management

So I open up Computer Management on my file serving computer in what has to be the first time in months or maybe even over a year and see that the mirror I had created of my 1TB HDD has "failed redundancy". I guess the "backup" HDD is missing (at least Windows thinks it is). Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This raises a number of questions. How long has my mirror been missing? And why didn't Windows tell me? What I would have preferred is if Windows maybe, idk... refused to work until the problem was fixed instead or something.

Is there any way to set it up so that next time it does this? So that next time when I have a potentially dead hard drive I find out about it that minute instead of finding out months and months after the fact?

Comment: if there is no such a tool you could make your own tool that notifies if one of your drives missing.

Comment: Have you checked the `notification center` icon in your task bar?  Most events like this can be placed there.  I don't have access to the exact name of the notification center but you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

To find out when the failure has happened go to the `Event Viewer\Windows Logs\System` and look for the following event:

```
Source:     ftdisk
Event Log:  System
Event ID:   6
Event Type: Error

The device filename that is part of a fault tolerance set has failed and will no longer be used.
```

To receive an e-mail notification about such events in the future - right-click on the event and select `Attach Task To This Event...` then choose `Send an e-mail` as the action for the task.

Comment: I'm not seeing it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ME6OC.png Also how would I attach a task to that event if that event wasn't in my logs? ie. if I were to do a fresh reformat at some point and wanted that task attached to that event. How would I do it?

Comment: You can create the task with `Task Scheduler\Event Viewer Tasks\Create Basic Task`

Answer (score 4):

There is a lengthy thread that discussed this exact problem on Microsoft TechNet:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5d3c3d5c-38ee-4a3d-9243-17712556eab8/windows-7-has-no-notification-of-raid-failure?forum=w7itprogeneral

The lack of any external notification for a failed redundancy, is a massive problem under Windows 7.  Short of going into Disk Management and manually checking it, there is no known alternate method to verify this.

The proposed solution above only works when you have *already* experienced a drive failure, and received an error code to which you can set up email alerts.

Windows should really inform you immediately when the failure occurs.

Under Windows 8 / 8.1 / 10, the 'Storages Spaces' control panel replaces the mirrored volume Disk Management functionality.  Storage Spaces will deliver notifications about a Failed Redundancy via the Action Center (which will display an alert notification in your task bar).

Comment: I had no idea about the new "Storage Spaces" feature -- thanks!